# Write method so that the main code is replaced by simpler code

Tags: java, methods

Use a method to replace this main code into a simpler code that calls the method mphAndMinutesToMiles().

```
public class CalcMiles {
       public static void main(String [] args) {
          double milesPerHour;
          double minutesTraveled;
          double hoursTraveled;
          double milesTraveled;

      milesPerHour = scnr.nextDouble();
      minutesTraveled = scnr.nextDouble();

      hoursTraveled = minutesTraveled / 60.0;
      milesTraveled = hoursTraveled * milesPerHour;

      System.out.println("Miles: " + milesTraveled);
   }
}






import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalcMiles {

   double calcMilesTraveled(double milesPerHour, double minutesTraveled) {
        double hoursTraveled = minutesTraveled / 60.0;
        double milesTraveled = hoursTraveled * milesPerHour;
        return milesTraveled;
   }

   public static void main(String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double milesPerHour;
      double minutesTraveled;

      milesPerHour = scnr.nextDouble();
      minutesTraveled = scnr.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Miles: " + mphAndMinutesToMiles(milesPerHour, minutesTraveled));
   }
}
```

Every time I run this code it keeps on giving me this error I have no idea what it means and I don't know how to fix this.

```
CalcMiles.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
      System.out.println("Miles: " + mphAndMinutesToMiles(milesPerHour, minutesTraveled));
                                     ^
  symbol:   method mphAndMinutesToMiles(double,double)
  location: class CalcMiles
1 error
```

Comment: I don't see a method named `mphAndMinutesToMiles()`.  Did I miss it?

Comment: @markspace The compiler doesn't seem to see it either. So I guess you did not miss it.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static double mphAndMinutesToMiles(double milesPerHour, double minutesTraveled) {
  double mphAndMinutesToMiles; 
    double hoursTraveled = minutesTraveled / 60.0;
    double milesTraveled = hoursTraveled * milesPerHour;
    return milesTraveled;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Change `calcMilesTraveled(double milesPerHour, double minutesTraveled)`  to be
`mphAndMinutesToMiles(double milesPerHour, double minutesTraveled)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other example of how to do it. Few more lines of code but I figure I would it here as an example.

```js
public static double mphAndMinutesToMiles(double milesPerHour, double minutesTraveled) {
      double hoursTraveled;
      double milesTraveled;     
      
      hoursTraveled = minutesTraveled / 60.0;
      milesTraveled = hoursTraveled * milesPerHour;
      
      return milesTraveled;
```